# Spring, AbstractBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В spring-е наткнулся на этот класс. В методе на картинке получается, что если текущий parentBeanFactory не null и если он не равен тому, который нам прислали, вылетает исключение, что текущий уже равен тому, который прислали. Может кто-нибудь пояснить?

Answer (score 1):

А в чем вопоос?

Метод исключает повторную установку фабрики которая отличается от уже установленной.

Вас смущает то что проверка избыточна?

Вероятно создатель класса зачем-то подразумевал что повторная установка той же фабрики - это корректная ситуация.

Какой в этом сакральный смысл - мне кажется на этот вопрос сможет ответить только автор.

Comment: Суть метода set - дать возможность установить какое-то значение извне. А здесь как-то непонятно. Ну, да видимо, вопрос к автору класса.